# How to pass user data into a JSON file using Laravel one to one

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am having issues getting user data in a JSON file am using one to one relationship
this is my PostRequest Model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PostRequest extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'artisan_id');
    }
}
```

User model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laratrust\Traits\LaratrustUserTrait;
use App\Models\Verify;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Crypt;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use LaratrustUserTrait;
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;
    
    public function PostRequest(){
        return  $this->hasOne(PostRequest::class, 'artisan_id');
    }
}
```

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

use App\Models\PostRequest;
use App\Models\User;

class ChatController extends Controller
{
    public function getMessages(){

        return view('user/message'); //response()->json($contacts);
    }
    public function getContact(){
        $email = Auth::user()->email;
        
            $contacts = PostRequest::select('artisan_id')->where('email', '=', $email)
            ->limit('1')
            ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
            ->user();
            return response()->json($contacts);
        //}

        
    }

}
```

if run the above controller I get this error msg

> [14:09:51] LOG.error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder:: user() {"userId":15,"exception":{}

If I run this I get all data, buh den I need a specific data

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

use App\Models\PostRequest;
use App\Models\User;

class ChatController extends Controller
{
    public function getMessages(){

        return view('user/message'); //response()->json($contacts);
    }
    public function getContact(){
        $email = Auth::user()->email;
        
            $contacts = PostRequest::all();
            return response()->json($contacts);
        //}

        
    }

}
```

Comment: you didn't execute the query yet, `orderBy` is adding to the query that is being built, you would have to call something like `first` to retrieve the result (model or `null`) then be able to call a method on the model ... though calling `user()` would just give you another Relationship/Builder object and not a result either

Comment: so i can replace orderBy with first()?

Comment: no, add `first()` after the `orderBy` so you can actually get the result

Comment: thanks man, no more errors but it returns empty data

Comment: because `user()` returns the relationship(builder), not a result ... you would have to call `first()` on that or use the dynamic property for the relationship instead, `->user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this query:

```
$email = Auth::user()->email;
$contacts = PostRequest::where('email', $email)->first()->user;
return response()->json($contacts);
```

Comment: same empty array, or am i getting something wrong somewhere

Comment: thanks @lagbox you've been looking out on me here i appreciate you man, its worjing now i added ordeyBy('id', 'DESC') to your answer and it returns the data

Comment: @lagbox am having issues passing the data into my vue am using this code to get the user data am i on track?                 <ul>
            <li v-for="contact in contacts" :key="contact.user.id">
            <div class="avatar">
                <img :src="contact.user.reqPhoto" :alt="contact.name">
            </div>
            <div class="contact">
                <p class="name">{{contact.user.name}}</p>
                <p class="email">{{contact.user.email}}</p>
            </div>
            </li>
        </ul>

Comment: but then if i select all i returns the data

Comment: can you check this last comment to see if you can help?